# Permalinks setting

Tags: permalinks

so, I know this is kind of a basic question, but it somehow oddly doesn't work for me.

What I want:

- https://example.com/blog/thema/*categoryname*/*postname* (for posts)
- https://example.com/blog/thema/*categoryname* (for categories)

Here are my settings:
[image]

Sadly that doesn't work. Here is a detailed information on what works on what settings:

- **Posts:** `/blog/thema/%category%/%postname%/` + **Category:** `blog/thema` = categories work, posts getting 404
- **Posts:** `/%category%/%postname%/` + **Category:** `blog/thema` = categories work, posts are `example.com/categoryname/postname`
- **Posts:** `/thema/%category%/%postname%/` + **Category:** `blog/thema` = categories work, posts are `example.com/thema/categoryname/postname`
- **Posts:** `/blog/thema/%category%/%postname%/` + **Category:** `thema` = posts work as `example.com/blog/thema/categoryname/postname/` but categories work like `example.com/thema/categoryname`

Maybe someone can help me. I won't mind if this is only solvable with some htaccess magic or whatever. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have them share the same slug, but you need to manually resolve conflicts yourself. You have to check if the end of the requested URL is an existing term, and reset the query vars accordingly if it's not found:

```
function wpd_post_request_filter( $request ){
    if( array_key_exists( 'category_name' , $request )
        && ! get_term_by( 'slug', basename( $request['category_name'] ), 'category' ) ){
            $request['name'] = basename( $request['category_name'] );
            $request['post_type'] = 'post';
            unset( $request['category_name'] );
    }
    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'wpd_post_request_filter' );
```

The obvious downsides to this are an extra trip to the database for every post or category view, and the inability to have a category slug that matches a post slug.

Comment: Thank you for the effort! This seems like a nice workaround and (atleast on my dev) worked. In the meanwhile I've found another solution based on Jacob's comments.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with what you're trying to do is that with your desired structure it's impossible to tell if a URL is for a subcategory or a post.

Take this URL, for example:

```
http://example.com/blog/thema/abc/def/
```

Is `def` a *post* in the `abc` category? Or is `def` a *subcategory* of `abc`? I can't tell by looking at the URL, and neither can WordPress. The issue is that WordPress isn't going to try both options.

WordPress is only ever going to look for one type of content when parsing the URL. So when WordPress sees that URL it checks if there's a subcategory of `abc` called `def`, and if that category doesn't exist WordPress will return a 404. This is why you're getting a 404 when attempting to view a post.

You're going to need to add something to the structure to differentiate a post from a subcategory. For example, if you used `/blog/post/%category%/%postname%` as the structure, then the above URL would look like this for a subcategory:

```
http://example.com/blog/thema/abc/def/
```

And this for a post:

```
http://example.com/blog/post/abc/def/
```

Comment: The explanation makes sense, but it still isn't working. I am thinking it might be some collision between the category permlink and the post permlink.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that might have been a bad suggestion. The URL will still look like a 3rd-level category.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative suggestion, however it's unfortunately even further from what you originally wanted. But I don't think you have many options.

Comment: Well thanks for the input for sure. But there has to be some solution, tho. It is possible with any other cms and if it's not possible with wordpress, then there has to be some htaccess workaround.

Comment: thinking about it, I just figured out that it doesn't really make sense. why would wordpress change it's behaviour just because I added something before the %vars% ? The normal behaviour is `/%category%/%postname%/` so based on your theory it would already have problems with the default setting.

Comment: No it wouldn't. If you set the structure to `/%category%/%postname%/` then categories still have `/category/` as the base.

Comment: not since 5.0 I think. Not sure about the exact version but it's been recently changed.

Comment: What? No it hasn't.

Comment: You might be using a plugin, like Yoast, that removes the `/category/` base. But to do this  the plugin uses a lot of code to fix this issue, and that code probably isn't compatible with your desired structure. If so, you'll need to take the issue up with the plugin developer.

Comment: Well, I am using 5.0.1 and even without any plugins, it will remove the prefix of the category by default even if the structure for permalinks is `%category%/%postname%/`

Comment: What are you talking about? _No it doesn't_. I'm looking right at it. It even says "If you leave these blank the defaults will be used." above the category base settings. You can _change_ the prefix, but you cannot remove it.

Comment: So you are saying I am lying about a fresh blank wordpress 5.0.1 install NOT throwing out the category prefix at posts even though I am just right infront of it and trying it.

Comment: The category prefix is on _categories_. Not _posts_. That's what I said. Posts do not have the prefix, but categories do. This is why `/%category%/%postname%/` works.

Comment: yeah, the categories do. That's true. I've misread it as that the posts still would have th category prefix. Still this answer is not nearly solving my problem and as this works on all other CMS this has to be possible with wordpress somehow.

Comment: I think you still are wrong about the third level problem:
`/%category%/%postname%/` is the same as `/something/%category%/%postname%/` the thirdlevel would be between category and potname, so changing the category prefix could not interfer the sub category

Comment: If `/something/` is different for posts and categories, then no, they wouldn't be the same. Please read what I write before arguing with me. The example in my answer uses `/post/` for posts and `/thema/` for categories. For `/blog/post/abc/def/`, `def` cannot be a 2nd or 3rd level category because the path begins with `/post/`, which means that whatever the last slug is, it's a post.

Comment: you are explaining me a problem based on your "solution". Don't get me wrong, I am thankful for your effort but my settings are the ones I am using, not the one you suggested as this isn't solving my problem. I want `example.com/blog/thema/coolcategory/coolpost/` as post link and `example.com/blog/thema/coolcategory/` as category link. **Nothing else**. **Not** `example.com/blog/post/coolcategory/coolpost/`for posts and `example.com/blog/thema/coolcategory/` for categories.

Comment: any way to contact you? While your initial answer wasn't helpful, something out of your comments made me find a solution, I would like to send you the information so you can re-edit your answer for that fance "accepted answer" :P